# Angular http pass url params as fields /project/{id}

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a controller that is consuming url parameters in the form `/project/{id}`. Hoowever, my angular2 provider creates calls in the following form: `/project?id=xxxx`.
How can I tell angular to call the service with the url format it is waiting for? My angular provider method:

```
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('id', id);
    let requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
    requestOptions.search = params;
    return new Promise<Project>((resolve) =>
        this.http.get('/api/Project', requestOptions).subscribe(result => {
            resolve(result.json());
        })
    );
```

Comment: If you have a path parameter, why are you explicitly providing it as a query parameter? Don't you just want `this.http.get(\`/api/Project/${id}\`)...`? Also note that `Observable`s have a [`toPromise` method](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/topromise.md) (or you could *actually use observables*).

Comment: Stupid me, thanks both of you.